# Small problem to print the result in the GUI of a Java program

Tags: java, netbeans

Photo of graphic interface:

[image]

I'm creating a simple Java program, in which a user types a number, then clicks the calculate button, and the result that is the square root of the number typed in appears in the field.
But I'm having trouble making this little program.
The field for the user to enter the input number is called inputText.
I created a String variable called inputText to receive what the user typed in String format.
Then I created an integer variable called inputValueInteger to transform into an integer.
In the button to calculate the result, I called `calcButton`.
In this button's method, I called the calculate(`inputValueInInteger`) method. This `inputValueInInteger` variable must be taken from `resultFieldActionPerformed`.
In the `calcButtonActionPerformed` method, I called the calculate(`inputValueInInteger`) method.
This method (`inputValueInInteger`) calculates the result of the square of the number that was passed as a parameter.
However, I'm having trouble getting the GUI `resultField` field to print the result.
Please can someone help?

```
public class Calc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int inputValueInInteger;

    public Calc() {
        initComponents();
    }

 private void inputTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String inputFieldInString = inputText.getText().toString();
        inputValueInInteger = Integer.parseInt(inputFieldInString);
    }                                         

    private void resultFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        int result = calculate(inputValueInInteger);
        String resultInString = String.valueOf(result);
        resultField.setText(resultInString);
    }                                           

    private void calcButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        calculate(inputValueInInteger);
    }                                          
    
    public int calculate(inputValueInInteger) {
        return inputValueInInteger * inputValueInInteger;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new InterfaceGrafica().setVisible(true);
                calculate(inputValueInInteger);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton calcButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inputText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField resultField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: When the button is clicked you: 1) get the text from the text field 2) convert the String value to an int valud 3) calculate your result 4) display the result. So you only need a single listener. I don't know why our code has multiple listeners.

Comment: @camickr
Could you please write your code and post here?
Please, it will teach and help more people, ok? :)

I did all what you wrote. But it is causing error yet.
Please, could you write your fixed code?

Comment: That's not the way it works. We are not here to write the code for you. You need to post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Start by reading the Swing tutoriial on [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). It show how to copy text from a text field and display it in a JTextArea. So the concept is similar. Download the demo code and test it, then modify it for your requirement.